# How can I express "for any two distinct elements $x$ and $y$ of the class $K$, at least one of the formulas: $xRy$ and $yRx$ holds"

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I would like to express that sentence as $$\forall x,y\in K(xRy \lor yRx)$$ but how can I say that $x\neq y$? Like this? $$\forall x,y \in K((xRy \lor yRx) ∧ x\neq y)$$

Comment: On the use of $\land$ vs. $\to$ in quantification, see also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260428/why-can-we-use-implication-with-the-universal-quantifier-but-not-with-the-existe

Comment: If one of the answers below are satisfying for you, please accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the last statement is false because nothing in the quantifier prohibits $x=y$.  You can say 
$$\forall x,y∈K~(x \neq y \to (xRy ∨ yRx))$$
which says nothing about whether $xRx$ or not.  I think I have also seen
$$\forall \underset{\large x\neq y}{x,y∈K}~(xRy ∨ yRx)$$

Comment: Sorry, I missed your second line, when I wrote my answer!  This is fine!

Comment: @amWhy:  I added it a bit later.  I had trouble stacking the $x \neq y$.  I am still not happy with how small it is.

Comment: No worries.  For the course the OP seems to be studying, I think the second line nails it (the first formula you write in display mode).

Comment: @Graham Kemp:  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, a statement of the form

> For all $x \in X$ *which are* $P$, $Q$ holds

translates as

> $\forall x \in X (P \to Q)$

You can paraphrase your sentence as

> For all $x, y \in K$ *which are* distinct, $xRy$ or $yRx$ holds

so the formalization becomes

> $\forall x, y \in K (x \neq y \to (xRy \lor yRx))$

---

Your attempt is not an adequate formalization because it entails that all $x, y \in K$ *must* be distinct from each other (since $xRy \lor yRx$ *and* $x \neq y$ holds for all of them), but since the universal quantififier ranges over any possible combiniation of $x, y$, your formula must also be true for $x = y$, which is contradictory.
With the implication instead, the formula just says that *if* they are distinct, then $xRy$ or $yRx$ should hold, but if not, we don't care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105030/discussion-between-amwhy-and-lemontree).