# How do I express "A person in this arcade won a grand prize" and "Nobody in this arcade played Pac-man"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

If we have

A(X) = x is in this arcade

W(X) = "x won a grand prize"

P(x) = "x played Pac-Man"

how would I express "A person in this arcade won a grand prize," and "Nobody in this arcade played Pac-Man." As premises in a quantified logical statement.

What I have done so far is $\forall x(\neg A(x) \implies P(x))$
and $\exists x (A(x) \implies W(x)$

Comment: I don't think that I'm allowed to answer until you've shown work.  Place to start would be to consider the various ways of using the tools: $\forall x, ~\exists x,~$ and $~\neg (\cdots)$.  From this perspective, what have you tried and where are you having trouble?

Comment: yeah I edited the original post to show what I think the answer is

Answer (score 1):

> "A person in this arcade won a grand prize"

> $\exists x (A(x) \implies W(x))$

See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487910/why-cant-we-use-implication-for-the-existential-quantifier) for a detailed explanation of why your formulization is incorrect: As a rule of thumb, with $\exists$ use $\land$ and with $\forall$ use $\implies$, so instead write

> $\exists x(A(x) \land W(x))$

---

> "Nobody in this arcade played Pac-Man."

> $\forall x(\neg A(x) \implies P(x))$

Your formula says "Everyone who is not in this arcade played Pac-Man". But what you want to say is "Everyone who is in this arcade did not play Pac-Man", that is, the negation should be applied to the playing Pac-Man, not to the being in the arcade:

> $\forall x (A(x) \implies \neg P(x))$

Comment: +1 nice detail....

Answer (score 0):

$[~\exists x ~(A(x) \wedge W(x))~]$ 
and 
$\{\neg ~~[\exists x ~(A(x) \wedge P(x))~]~~\}$.